# How do I add images to a PyPI readme (that works on GitHub)?

Tags: python, github, pypi, restructuredtext, readme

In my readme on GitHub I have several images that are present there in my project's source tree which I reference successfully with directives like

```
.. image:: ./doc/source/_static/figs/moon_probe.png
```

I would also like to have these images appear when this same readme is generated in PyPi.

How do I (a) ensure that images are present on PyPi for the readme to access and (b) formulate the `.. image::` directive to access them?

Answer (score 47):

PyPI will not read your package distributions for the image. You have to use the image's **external link**, for example:

```
.. image:: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/greyli/flask-share/master/images/demo.png
```

If you are using Markdown description, use this:

```
![](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/greyli/flask-share/master/images/demo.png)
```

Be sure to replace the URL in the above examples with your image URL, here I use the image hosted by GitHub, the real demo is on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Share/).

P.S. To get the image's raw link on GitHub, right-click the image and choose ***Copy image address***.

Comment: Doesn't work, requires a token that expires now.  I've seen one or two that still work, but they seem to be in markdown rather than RST.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. In markdown, a link would look like this: `![](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/project/branch/image.png)`

Comment: @MikeConigliaro Is it important to use `![](...)` rather than `![alt text](...)`? The latter just displays the alt text on PyPi for me.

Comment: Does this also work for gifs? Are they displayed on PyPi?

Comment: @CGFoX I'm not sure, but here's where I used it: https://pypi.org/project/smtptester/

Comment: works for me in md w the normal github.com url ending w `?raw=true`

Comment: @CGFoX no, you can use alt text and it will render fine, that was just an example. You can see for example the [`requests` readme](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) uses an image [with alt text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/psf/requests/master/README.md).

Answer (score 11):

Go to the image address in the Github repository. The path shown will be like this:
https://github.com/tensorbored/kds/blob/master/docs/_static/readme_lift.png
[image]
Change the **blob** term in the image address to **raw**
https://github.com/tensorbored/kds/raw/master/docs/_static/readme_lift.png
[image]

Comment: I was just going to do this, but if I understand correctly, then ALL PyPi versions, as they age, will continue to pull their images from the `master` branch, meaning things like screenshots might represent a newer version of the codebase than what is *actually* only that PyPi release. It works, but it might be disingenuous.

Comment: @EvanRusackas You can replace `master`/`main` with a git tag name like `v0.1.0`, and update it at release time. A tool like BumpVer could help like this.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `?raw=True` at the end of GitHub image link seems to work.

example:

```
![Sample image](https://github.com/usename/reponame/blob/master/sample.png?raw=True)
```

<sub>I had found this somewhere on the internet previously, but couldn't find it now. I'll credit the original author when I find it again.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If you have your images on Github, navigate to the image then right click on download button and copy link address:

[image]

Then you can add it in your README.md file:

```
![](https://github.com/your_username/your_repository/raw/master/images/img2.png)
```

It should be rendered properly both on Github and PyPi.

Answer (score 0):

The long_description_content_type should be text/x-rst if you use restructured text syntax (README.rst). Assuming that is what you are using based on ".. image::". If you save the image on GitHub and use that external link for the image then it works (typically something like raw.githubusercontent.com.... as described in one of the above answers).

It does work as shown in this pypi package:
https://pypi.org/project/gammath-spot/