# How to create a README.md that shows pictures on PyPI?

Tags: python, github, pip, markdown, pypi

I created a python package called [ExoplanetPy on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ExoplanetPy/), but the pictures on the project page seem to not be rendered for some reason.
For context, the README.md displays pictures on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ExoplanetPy/ExoplanetPy).

How do I edit the markdown file such that I can have pictures when I publish it on PyPI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [here - Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983209/how-do-i-add-images-to-a-pypi-readme-that-works-on-github)

> PyPI will not read your package distributions for the image. You have
> to use the image's external link.

So change the code to:

```
![](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ExoplanetPy/ExoplanetPy/master/images/logo_400.png "ExoplanetPy logo")
```